# Cardinal exponentiation ambiguity

Tags: set-theory

This is a following passage from Jech on cardinal exponentiation.

[image]

Am I correct in that $\kappa^\lambda$ means two different things here? Namely, that the first $\kappa^\lambda$ is the set of all functions $f: \lambda \to \kappa$, while the second $\kappa^\lambda$ denotes the cardinality of the aforementioned set.

Comment: Quite right. For this reason some writers prefer $^\lambda\kappa$ for the set of functions.

Comment: Speaking of ambiguity, what about your "passage from Jech"? Assuming you mean the mathematician Tom Jech and not some other person named Jech, I believe that he has written several books, some of which exist in multiple editions.

Comment: @bog This is from Set Theory by Jech.

Comment: Yes, this is a known problem. It could also be ordinal exponentiation. If only we could somehow have a notion of context from which to infer the meaning. Oh wait!  We did have that! :-)

Comment: Which edition?$\ $

Comment: @bof Third edition.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Side question, but now I'm not so sure why the 'and so' follows. The $\alpha^\lambda$'s are not disjoint sets. To my understanding $\sum_{\alpha < \kappa} |\alpha|^\lambda$ is the cardinality of the disjoint union $\bigcup_{\alpha < \kappa} A_\alpha$ where $|A_\alpha| = |\alpha|^\lambda$ ?

Comment: We can prove that this doesn't matter. It takes a few cardinal arithmetic theorems, but nothing too fancy.